# How do I validate a form element on key press?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have code that validates a form before it is sent to the server and what I want to achieve is to validate the form elements on keypress. So, when the cursor is currently in a form element, I want to test the form element while the user is typing and display an error message if there is an error. Currently, what I have is tests that run when the cursor is out of focus.

I tried the event "keydown", but then the code does not display the errors.

HTML code:

```
<form action="" id="form">

<input id="name" type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter your name">
<span id="name-feedback"></span>
<br>

<input id="password" type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter a password">
<span id="password-feedback"></span>
<br>

<input type="range" name="" min="1" max="10" value="7" id="amount">

<input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked id="checkbox"><label for="cb">Check me
</label>
<span id="checkbox-feedback"></span>
<br>

<textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<span id="message-feedback"></span>
<br>


<br>
<input type="submit" name="" value="Submit me">


</form>
```

JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$(function() {

  var form = $("#form");

  enableFastFeedback(form);

 form.submit(function(event) {
    // First, read out all entered values.
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var checked = $("#checkbox").is(":checked");

    // Then we use our validation functions (defined below) to check each input.
    validateNameField(name, event);
    validatePasswordField(password, event);
    validateMessageField(message, event);
    validateCheckboxField(checked, event);
  });

  // In the following, we define helper functions that each validate
  // one of the inputs. These will be used further down by our validation
  // functions.

  function isValidName(name) {
    return name.trim().length >= 2;
  }

  function isValidPassword(password) {
    return password.length >= 6 && /.*[0-9].*/.test(password);
  }

  function isValidMessage(message) {
    return message.trim() !== "";
  }

  // Next, we define the actual validation functions which use the helpers from
  // above. These validation functions add a hint for the user for each invalid
  // input and prevent the form from submitting if the input is invalid.

  // First, show a hint if the name is not valid or remove the hint if it's
  // now valid.
  function validateNameField(name, event) {
    if (!isValidName(name)) {
      $("#name-feedback").text("Please enter at least two characters");
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $("#name-feedback").text("");
    }
  }

  // Do the same for the other inputs.
  function validatePasswordField(password, event) {
    if (!isValidPassword(password)) {
      $("#password-feedback").text("The password should have at least 6 characters and contain a number");
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $("#password-feedback").text("");
    }
  }

  function validateMessageField(message, event) {
    if (!isValidMessage(message)) {
      $("#message-feedback").text("Please enter a message.");
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $("#message-feedback").text("");
    }
  }

  function validateCheckboxField(isChecked, event) {
    if (!isChecked) {
      $("#checkbox-feedback").text("Please agree to this.");
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $("#checkbox-feedback").text("");
    }
  }

function enableFastFeedback(formElement) {

  var nameInput = formElement.find("#name");
  var passwordInput = formElement.find("#password");
  var messageInput = formElement.find("#message");
  var checkboxInput = formElement.find("#checkbox");

  nameInput.blur(function(event) {
    var name = $(this).val();
    validateNameField(name, event);

    if(!isValidName(name)) {
      $(this).css("padding-bottom", "25px");
      $(this).css("border", "2px solid #600");
    }
    else {
      $(this).css("padding-bottom", "25px");
      $(this).css("border", "2px solid green");
    }
  });

 passwordInput.blur(function(event) {
     var password = $(this).val();
    validatePasswordField(password, event);

    if(!isValidPassword(password)) {
      $(this).css("padding-bottom", "25px");
      $(this).css("border", "2px solid #600");
    }
    else {
      $(this).css("padding-bottom", "25px");
      $(this).css("border", "2px solid green");
    }
  });

 messageInput.blur(function(event) {
     var message = $(this).val();
    validateMessageField(message, event);

    if(!isValidMessage(message)) {
      $(this).css("padding-bottom", "25px");
      $(this).css("border", "2px solid #600");
    }
    else {
      $(this).css("padding-bottom", "25px");
      $(this).css("border", "2px solid green");
    }
  });

 checkboxInput.change(function(event) {
     var checkbox = $(this).is(":checked");
    validateCheckboxField(checkbox, event);

    if(!checkbox) {
      $(this).add("label[for='cb']").css("padding-bottom", "25px");
      $(this).add("label[for='cb']").css("border", "2px solid #600");
    }
    else {
      $(this).add("label[for='cb']").css("padding-bottom", "25px");
      $(this).add("label[for='cb']").css("border", "2px solid green");
    }
  });


}
});
```

So, how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Please use onkeypress html attribute to call javascript function to validate field: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer Roby Raju Oommen, I used onkeypress: nameInput.keypress(function(event) { ... , but it didn't work; on focus, the element doesn't display/register the keys pressed.

Comment: What if someone turns off JS on their browser?

Comment: dale landry, then server validation will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I removed blur and put keyup event in its place and now the correct behavior occurs.

Comment: You should instead use `input` event. This takes care of copy/paste, drag/drop, etc.  `keyup` event is limited.

Comment: Thank you ruleboy21, I am now using the input event and it is better than keyup.